# Find the n-th term for fibonacci I keep getting an error

Tags: python, fibonacci

I'm trying to implement the function fibonacci(n) that returns the n-th Fibonacci number. For n = 5 I'm supposed to get 8, but I get 7.

Here is my code:

```
def fibonacci(n-1):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 2
    else:
         fn = (n-1) + (n-2)
         return fn
```

Comment: this is not valid python code and could not possibly run - `n-1` is invalid syntax for parameter in function signature. Post your actual code.

Comment: Try to think about how you can tackle the problem using recursion, where a function calls itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct fibonacci sequence is 0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5 ...

So, the first `if` return and the `elif n == 2` condition are wrong. The correct code should be:

```py
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 0 or n == 1:
        return n
    else: 
         return fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
```

Also, `n-1` is not valid when passed as argument. You should use just `n`

Answer (score 1):

Your formula is wrong - you need :

```
def fibonacci(n):
    if n == 0 or n ==1:
        return 1
    elif n == 2:
        return 2
    else: 
         fn = fibonacci(n-1) + fibonacci(n-2)
         return fn
```

Notice that this is calling the fibonacci function again which is the right thing to do.